# Make a footer page unlinkable, but have sub pages linkable underneath it

Tags: headers

We are not developers by any means, but we do try to work on what we can on the backend of our Craft CMS site that was created from a web company. We recently decided to have a footer page titled "Supportive Customers" that doesn't link to an actual page. When you hover over it, two sub pages appear and ARE clickable.

I know in wordpress this is a simple task of creating a "link" instead of a page and using "#" so it doesn't link anywhere. However, Craft CMS doesn't seem to be that easy. Is there a simple solution for this that we're missing on the back end? Just wanted to know if this is something we can do without coding, or if we need to source this project to our developers.

I did attach a quick mockup of what the footer looks like - again, Supportive Customers is NOT clickable.

[image]Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to this, because it depends entirely on how the footer is coded. There is no standard solution for menus in Craft CMS like in WordPress. Developers are free to decide where to get the content for the footer navigation from and what interfaces to provide to manage menu structures through the backend.

The footer menu might be hardcoded in the template, in this case the only way to change it would be by finding the Twig template and editing it manually. Or it may come from some source like an Entries field where you select the entries to be displayed in the footer menu. Maybe this solution supports 'passive' links like that and maybe it doesn't, there's no way to tell without looking at the code and the data structures for the menu.

One popular solution for building menus is the [*Navigation* plugin](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/navigation/), which supports menu nodes that don't link to anything by default (those are called *Passive nodes* by the plugin).

In the medium to long term, you can't effectively make structural changes like this to a Craft site without a developer who knows their way around Craft CMS. I would reach out to the web development company that built the site and ask if this is already possible. If not, ask them for a quote to extend the footer with that functionality. I would also recommend signing a support contract with them so you have someone who will take care of updates as well as provide support and feature development.